# QGIS Speed up slow virtual layer

Tags: qgis, sql, performance, virtual-layer

In QGIS I have a virtual layer which does a line generation based on a point shape. The point shape has about 700 point geometries and 26 attribute fields.

```
SELECT  a.Name, a.FromNode, a.ToNode, a.Length, a.Roughness, 
        a.InOffset, a.OutOffset, a.InitFlow, a.MaxFlow, a.Shape, 
        a.Geom1, a.Geom2, a.Geom3, a.Geom4, a.Barrels, a.Culvert, 
        a.Shp_Trnsct, a.Kentry, a.Kexit, a.Kavg, a.FlapGate, 
        a.Seepage, a.Annotation, a.Variante, 
        makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry 
FROM pointshape a, pointshape b 
WHERE b.Name = a.ToNode
```

Unfortunately the resulting virtual polyline layer ist quite slow on rendering and espacially on opening the attribute table.
I need the virtual polylines to run on the point layer, because I want to edit only the point layer.
If I do the same on a temporal scratch layer there are no peferormance issues.

Comment: What software is this? Can you add a tag for it and maybe mention it in the title?

Comment: I've edited the question - thanks!

Comment: Virtual layers are often slow. Can you export the result to a geopackage?

Comment: A bit more context would help. What do you need the virtual layer (the lines) for? Visualization only? Geoprocessing? Could you only run the `makeline` part, without loading the attributes, save the lines and then join attributes by location? A lot of different workflows are possible, but depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @BERA Yes I am able to export the result to a geopackage.

Comment: @Babel I editet the question. I need the geometry (polylines) and all the attributes as basis for an export to third party software. The workflow is 1. edit point layer 2. generate virtual layer as polylines 3. export both to 3rd party software. Sure, i can use the "geometry by expression tool" to generate the polyline layer, but I like to use the virtual solution because I can see changes on the point layer dynamically.

Comment: If I take the data from the point layer to a temporal scratch layer and then use the temporal scratch layer to generate the virtual point layer there are no performance issues in rendering the geometry and opening the attribute table.

Comment: What file formats are your source layers?

Comment: Maybe creating a spatial index helps? Using a PostGIS view might be another option.

Comment: If you save the layer as a geopackage the geopackage layer will be a lot faster

Comment: @Babel - I've allready tryed this, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution (thanks @bugmenot123, @Babel for the hints) was to save the pointlayer as geopackage. Originally it was ESRI-Shape. Switching to geopackage will speed up rendering the virtual polylines and opening the attributetable way much faster.